# Discrepancy between Matlab and Mathematica Fourier parameters

Tags: fourier-analysis, matlab

MATLAB and *Mathematica* have different FFT normalization parameters. This is easy to change in *Mathematica* with the `FourierParameters ->` argument, but anything having to do with this in MATLAB seems to have been deprecated, or only working for the non-discrete case. So, I want to try and perform operations on my MATLAB FFT function to have it match the *Mathematica* one.

I start with `fft([1 1 2 2 1 1 0 0])` in MATLAB:
[image]

Then, exploring with the parameters in *Mathematica*:

[image]

Aha! So, the *Mathematica* parameters, `{1, 1}`, give me the values I got from MATLAB, while the *Mathematica* parameters `{0, 1}`, that are used for default *Mathematica* FFT behavior, seem to be scaling those of `{1, 1}` by a factor of `(sqrt(2/pi)/2)`.

But oh no, applying that factor in MATLAB gives me
[image]

which is close to, but not quite, the data I want. How can I replicate this correctly in MATLAB?

Comment: [Always check the definitions being used in whatever system you're using](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118092), be it *Mathematica* or MATLAB.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fourier.html), *Mathematica* defaults to defining `y = Fourier[x]` as:

$$ y_k = \frac1{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{j=1}^n x_j e^{2 \pi i (j-1) (k-1)/n} $$

From [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html), MATLAB defaults to defining `y = fft(x)` as:

$$ y_k = \sum_{j=1}^n x_j e^{-2 \pi i (j-1) (k-1)/n} $$

MATLAB further defines `x = ifft(y)` as:

$$ x_k = \frac1n \sum_{j=1}^n y_j e^{2 \pi i (j-1) (k-1)/n} $$

As we can see, MATLAB's `fft` differs in the sign of the exponent from *Mathematica*'s definition which makes it slightly more annoying to use as a substitute (you have to either time reverse things, or conjugate the answer and only work for real valued data), but MATLAB's `ifft` matches the *Mathematica* definition in all but normalization.

Thus we can make MATLAB emulate *Mathematica*'s `y = Fourier[x]` for arbitrary complex data `x` via:

```
y = sqrt(length(x)) ifft(x)
```

We can equivalently also make *Mathematica* emulate MATLAB's `y = fft(x)` for real data via:

```
y = Sqrt[Length[x]] Conjugate[Fourier[x]]
```

... or, perhaps more idiomatically, and also for complex data:

```
y = Fourier[x, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]
```

Comment: For MATLAB, you would actually use [`ifft()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ifft.html) instead if you want to emulate the *Mathematica* default: `sqrt(length(x)) ifft(x)`.

Comment: Sounds better. That also has the right behavior for complex data. I'm not familiar with MATLAB, so I literally just pieced together something that worked from the definitions in the documentation and seemed to work in Octave. I'll edit it.

Comment: @user3047059 How would matlab's ifft function look like in MMA? I tried using InverseFourier[y,FourierParameter->{1,-1}] in MMA12 Windows 7 and it doesn't work (doesn't return x).