# Fourier Scaling Issue

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

First a little background: I’ve looked at the following discussions on StackExchange and still racking my head on Fourier

[What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/118092#118092)

[Discrepancy between Matlab and Mathematica Fourier parameters](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/158486/discrepancy-between-matlab-and-mathematica-fourier-parameters)

[Comparing ordinates between FourierTransform and Fourier](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129702/comparing-ordinates-between-fouriertransform-and-fourier)

Let’s Import the data and define a couple of helper functions.

** [waveform data link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/khxo8ixtq7hzkgo/inputWaveForm.csv?dl=0)**

```
 waveForm = Import[“filename.csv", "CSV”];


myFFT[a : {{_, _} ...}] := 
Module[{time, y, dt, ft, len, front, back, 
freq},(*Extract data and take the Fourier transform*)

time = a[[All, 1]];
y = a[[All, 2]];
dt = time[[2]] - time[[1]];
ft = Abs[Fourier[y, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]];

(*Identify positive and negative frequencies.Zero frequency mode \
 appears at position 1*)

len = If[EvenQ[Length[ft]], Length[ft] + 1, Length[ft]];
front = Take[ft, Ceiling[len/2]];
back = Reverse[Take[ft, -Floor[len/2]]];
ft = front + PadLeft[back, Length[front]];
(*Make frequency units and return FFT*)
freq = Table[i/dt/Length[a], {i, 0, Length[ft] - 1}];
Transpose[{freq, ft}]]


 integrateList[t_] := Differences[#1].MovingAverage[#2, 2] & @@ 
  Transpose[t]; (*Trapezoidal Rule *)
```

Let’s compute the power of the signal

```
 signal = {#1, #2 - 5.1875} & @@@  waveForm; (*Remove DC *)
 signalSquared = {#1, #2^2} & @@@ signal;
 fft = myFFT[signalSquared];
```

Let’s now do a Parseval’s Theorem sanity check and compare the area under the curve in time domain and frequency domain to make sure that they are equal

```
 integrateList@signalSquared[[1 ;; All]]
 2*integrateList[fft] (*since we are looking at only half the curve *)
```

I get the following results:

```
 > Time Domain Area Under the Curve = 4.9616 e-6
 > Frequency Domain Area Under the Curve = 8.2740 e+8
```

Clearly a big difference in area! I’ve tried tinkering with the Fourier Parameters but no avail… Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where you have `i/dt/Length[a]` I suspect you want `i*dt/Length[a]`. There may be other issues but that change at least puts things in the correct ballpark.

Comment: Changing that throws the frequency axis way off…. i/dt/Length[a] gives me the correct frequency range [the time domain signal ~10 MHz broadband pulse]  and the gives me the zeros in the right place.